# SharePoint 2019 SSL Redirection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, site-collection

I have a SharePoint 2019 Publishing site that I have configured and built and works fine in a high-level.

I have configured the AAM for Internet zone with two Internal URLs (HTTP - HTTPS) and one Public URL to ensure all the traffic is on HTTPS.

The site works fine working from my localhost or through my VPN tunnel, while it starts breaking if trying to access it anonymously. It starts asking for credentials multiple times and some times giving weird 401 or 403 errors.

I tried to do a lot of investigations and found in the logs that this breaking happens when the requests are on port 80, but things work fine on port 443.

So my aim is to make all requests on port 443 by trying to put a rewrite rule but thin starts giving ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS and things are breaking:

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

This is a sample of IIS logs and removed the IPs:

```
2023-10-11 11:22:44  GET /_catalogs/masterpage/Master/assets/images/logo.png - 80 - {ip} Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/117.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 https://{url}/ 401 0 0 3
```

I don't know if this might be the problem but the request is coming through port 80 to https and the response is 401, while if it is coming through 443 it works fine.

How can I get rid of this behavior ?